# Using a string in order to set property to orderby in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function with a LINQ query set up as follows:

```
public List<company> FetchSortedList(string cat)
{
   var aDTOList = (from s in db.companies
                   where s.category == cat
                   orderby s.name
                   select s).ToList();
}
```

I now need to change this function to allow the user to pass down another parameter called "field" which will a string value with the name of the property for the list to be sorted by. Is there anyway to do this similar to the above query, i.e.:

```
 public List<company> FetchSortedList(string cat, string prop)
 {
    var aDTOList = (from s in db.companies
                    where s.category == cat
                    orderby s[prop]
                    select s).ToList();
 }
```

(I know the above code doesn't work, just asking if there is anything akin to doing something like that)

Or will I need to do something else?

Comment: have a look at Dynamic Linq and the duplicate question

Comment: thanks I had a look around but think I must have used wrong wording, I'll look into both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct an `Expression` that should look like `x => x.SomePropertyToSortBy` and pass it to `OrderBy` method.